# IOS apps are no longer logging in via instagram

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, instagram

I get this error message anytime I want to login via instagram on IOS

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8e489f6

In apps like 
Instaround 
Instalook
Instamapia

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8e489f6

Comment: okay, thanks - how are you implementing the Instagram integration with your app? are you using an SDK calling the API? Can you show any code that shows your process please.

Answer (score 0):

Based from [Instagram Platform and documentation update](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/):

> Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process.
>
> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 1, 2016. On that date, **the app will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process.**

In my own understanding, if your app was one of those that were automatically moved to Sandbox Mode, the following should be done:

- You need to add sandbox users who will be able to test and authenticate your app.
- Once you have some sandbox users, you can have them go through the authorization flow and generate an access token.

May I suggest that it is still best that you go through the documentation for the complete guide regarding Sandbox Mode.

Additionally, this issue was also discussed in this [forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-are-not-a-sandbox-user-of-this-client-instagram-feed-error). I hope that helps.